# Yammer JavaScript SDK jQuery conflicts with local jQuery

Tags: yammer

Yammer SDK JavaScript is breaking today due to the Yammer jQuery that is being loaded. How do I not cause jQuery conflicts with Yammer SDK?

Comment: We are aware of an issue. Make sure to post through https://developer.yammer.com/feedback/bug/ when you find issues, or open a Microsoft Support case.

Comment: this issue was resolved yesterday. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

A temporary work around is to save off jQuery to a local var before loading yammer.

So

```
var __jQuery = jQuery, __$ = $;
<load yammer>
jQuery = __jQuery;
$ = __$;
```